# Async Fetch/Await breaking Vite Hot Reload

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuetify.js, vuejs3, vite

So I have a project using Vue 3 + Vite + Vuetify Alpha. On one of my pages I added in a function to fetch an API endpoint and retrieve data from a database. After adding this code the hot reload of the Vite dev server no longer works. If I make any changes to the project and save Vite reloads with no errors but my webpage goes white. If I completely restart the Vite dev server it works until I make another change in the project and save then its a white screen again till I restart the server. If I remove the code for the fetch/await, I don't have the problem anymore I can make changes and Vite hot reloads and displays the changes without any issue.

I checked the browser console after a reload when its displaying a blank page and I have an error stating "Cannot access 'router' before initialization' pointing to app.use(router) in main.ts . But I'm not sure what the problem is or how Vue router ties into the fetch/await call, but any advice would be appreciated.

```
//SplashPage.vue 
<script setup lang="ts">
import {computed, ref} from "vue";
import {useEventStore} from "@/stores/event.store";
import {url} from "@/main";

const curr_date = new Date().toDateString()
const searchQuery = ref("");
const store = useEventStore();
let eventsArray :Array<any> = [];

   (async () => {
      console.debug('FETCH');
      const response = await fetch(
          `${url}/event_name_search/`
      );
      const events = await response.json();
    events.searchResults.forEach((e :any) => {
        e.id = e.logid;
        e.label = e.title;
        e.date = curr_date;
      });
    eventsArray = events.searchResults
   })();


const searchEvents = computed(() => {
  if(searchQuery.value === ''){
    return []
  }
  return (eventsArray).filter((event) =>{
    if(event.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchQuery.value.toLowerCase())){
      return event
    }
  });
});

const selectEvent = (event :any) => {
  selectedEvent.value = event;
  searchQuery.value ='';
}
let selectedEvent = ref('')

</script>
```

```js
//main.ts
 import { createApp } from 'vue'
 import { createPinia } from 'pinia'
 import App from './App.vue'
 import router from './router/index'
 import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify'
 import { loadFonts } from './plugins/webfontloader'
 import './styles/_variables.scss'
 
 loadFonts()
 
 const app = createApp(App)
 export const url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000'
 app.use(router)
 app.use(vuetify)
 app.use(createPinia())
 app.mount('#app')
```

```
//App.vue
<script setup lang="ts">
</script>
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <Suspense>
        <template #default>
          <router-view/>
        </template>
        <template #fallback>
          <h1 style="color: red">ERROR!</h1>
        </template>
      </Suspense>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</template>
```

**EDIT**
So I created a dependency graph using madge on the advice of Estus. It found two circular dependencies, could this possibly be causing the issue?

[Dependency_Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6L9Gv.png)

Comment: where is `//fetch call` code, its unclear where are you running it?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone added more context. Its in one of my .vue files specifically one created for the default landing page for the web app.

Comment: I'm not sure if fixing this can help, but it's a mistake to put the code directly into setup with IIFE. It belongs to onMounted. The error is probably caused by dependency graph. It's unknown how modules used in the component are related to the router

Comment: @EstusFlask Oh, I was under the impression with the <script setup> tag and composition api, everything inside was run before mounting. I tried changing it what you recommended but unfortunately the hot reload still broke. Thank you for the help though, I will look into dependency graph.

Comment: @EstusFlask Added a picture of the dependency graph, idk if that sparks any ideas of what may be wrong? I see the circular dependencies but I am not sure why they exist or how they could cause the router issue.

Comment: Yes, CD could cause this. It's acceptable to have CD if it's justified, but it can affect the way import behave in some situations, e.g. hot reloading. Things that are used by async function are primary suspects , `@/main` and `@/stores/event.store`, since it behaves differently if they aren't used.  Do not import main anywhere. I see no reasons to keep `url` there.

Comment: When I migrated a project from vue-cli to vite I had a similar problem with a CD which I wasn't aware of. I managed to rewrite my code to get rid of it and had no issues after.